# Python library to display Venn diagrams

Tags: library, python, data-visualization, diagram

I am looking for a Python library that is able to produce [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). It should take as input two or three sets, and display a Venn diagram that represent the sets.

If possible:

- the number of items in each set can displayed.
- plots can be saved in some vectorial format.
- plots can be displayed in black and white (for some antique publication requirements).

The Python package [matplotlib-venn](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn) is great:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
set2 = set(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
set3 = set(['C', 'D',' E', 'F', 'G'])

venn3([set1, set2, set3], ('Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3'))
```

[image]

But it currently has an issue that cause some sets to have a [wrong count](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/issues/23).

Related:  [JavaScript library to display Venn diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7393/903)

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Comment: https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn