# Library to generate a scaled, 4-set Venn diagram

Tags: library, data-visualization

I am looking for a Python library that is able to produce a scaled, 4-set [Venn diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). Scaled means that the displayed areas should try to match the cardinality of each set. 4-set means I should be able to specify 4 sets.

For example, the following Venn diagrams is based on 4 sets (I, II, III and IV), but is not scaled:

[image]

(it was generated using the R package [VennDiagram](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/index.html) with the code:

```
library(VennDiagram);
# http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/VennDiagram/docs/venn.diagram
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/VennDiagram.pdf
# http://www.biomedcentral.com/content/supplementary/1471-2105-12-35-s3.r
# http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/35

# Figure 1D
venn.diagram(
    x = list(
        I = c(1:60, 61:105, 106:140, 141:160, 166:175, 176:180, 181:205, 206:220),
        IV = c(531:605, 476:530, 336:375, 376:405, 181:205, 206:220, 166:175, 176:180),
        II = c(61:105, 106:140, 181:205, 206:220, 221:285, 286:335, 336:375, 376:405),
        III = c(406:475, 286:335, 106:140, 141:160, 166:175, 181:205, 336:375, 476:530)
        ),
    filename = "1D-quadruple_Venn.tiff",
    col = "black",
    lty = "dotted",
    lwd = 4,
    fill = c("cornflowerblue", "green", "yellow", "darkorchid1"),
    alpha = 0.50,
    label.col = c("orange", "white", "darkorchid4", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "darkblue", "white", "white", "white", "white", "darkgreen", "white"),
    cex = 2.5,
    fontfamily = "serif",
    fontface = "bold",
    cat.col = c("darkblue", "darkgreen", "orange", "darkorchid4"),
    cat.cex = 2.5,
    cat.fontfamily = "serif"
    );
```

The Python package [matplotlib-venn](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn) does scale but [currently doesn't support more than 3 sets](https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn/issues/15):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
set1 = set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
set2 = set(['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
set3 = set(['C', 'D',' E', 'F', 'G'])

venn3([set1, set2, set3], ('Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3'))
```

[image]

Any language, OS and license is fine.

If possible:

- the number of items in each set can displayed.
- plots can be saved in some vectorial format.
- plots can be displayed in black and white (for some antique publication requirements).

I am not fully sure to what extent the request is feasible, e.g. Chen, Hanbo, and Paul C. Boutros. "[VennDiagram: a package for the generation of highly-customizable Venn and Euler diagrams in R.](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/35)" BMC bioinformatics 12.1 (2011): 35.:

> During development of the VennDiagram package, it was discovered that it was impossible to draw accurate, scaled Venn diagrams with three sets using circles.

Related:

- [JavaScript library to display Venn diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7393/903)
- [Python library to display Venn diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/25666/903)

Comment: I think there was an error regarding matplotlib-venn.  I fixed it, but you may wish to verify my correction.  :)

Comment: In Python, this may work but I couldn't install it yet https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn

Comment: Note that the numbers in the graphics example provided do not match those shown in the R code. With the R code, the dark blue 992 would be a 60.

Comment: https://github.com/tctianchi/pyvenn